# If subdomain else than www., redirect to www

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, nginx

In nginx config I have added

```
server_name *.example.com example.com;
```

If I will write only

```
server_name www.example.com example.com;
```

nginx `m.example.com` is redirecting to the first website configured in nginx configuration.

With the first line, my site shows same results on rails whatever subdomain is used: `m.example.com/hello` or `www.example.com/hello` and etc. It is ok, but it should be redirected to www.

So I need to redirect all other subdomains => `m.example.com/hello to www.example.com/hello` because of SEO. How can I do this redirection from `routes.rb`?

---

Now I'm using rule only to redirect from no subdomain `example.com/* to www.example.com/*`

```
constraints subdomain: false do
  get ':any', to: redirect(subdomain: 'www', path: '/%{any}'), any: /.*/
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this directly in Nginx if you wish.

```
server_name *.example.com example.com;

if ($host != 'www.example.com') {
    rewrite ^ http://www.example.com$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

Remove the permanent flag to stop this being a 301 redirect.